# Kendo grid time saved 4 hours ahead?

Tags: kendo-ui

In my Kendo Grid, I am using a time picker. But when I choose a time and save to database, its  adding 4 hours ahead of the selected time. Why is it so? Is it something to do with the culture?

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the timezone that you are using. Likely different in browser (KendoUI) and Database. Or just the opposite, correct saving but converted to UTC. Is that possible?

Comment: At the time its saved, its sending the right time to the database(i am using asp.net web api). but its saved incorrectly in the database

Comment: But the server receives it correctly? What does it receive... UTC?

Comment: Because JavaScript `Date` and SQL `DateTime` (I assume you are using SQL) do not like each other and conversions between the two are a nightmare.